# Volley, Webservices and login

Tags: android, web-services, asynchronous, request, android-volley

I'm trying to communicate with an API thanks to Volley.
Ideally, I would like to be able to use a DataAccessLayer like this:

```
DAL.addTransaction(value, description);
```

The main problem is, that before doing any call to the API, I must login.
This login request will return me an access token, that will have to be integrated in any other call.

I was thinking about doing a login in the DAL constructor, but in fact, since the requests are made asynchronously, the addTransaction request could be refused if it reaches the API before the login request.

Do you have any clue how to develop this kind of Data access layer without dirty coding?

I have been trying to play with listeners, but it's far less easy than javascript's callbacks function.

Thanks in advance.